# QML: Initialize empty list

Tags: qml

I want to do the following:

```
property list<MenuItem> menuItems: []
```

This fails with:

```
Unexpected token `]'
```

However, this works:

```
property list<MenuItem> menuItems: [MenuItem{}]
```

So how do I initialize an empty list here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
property list<MenuItem> menuItems
```

The declaration with `[]` requires at least one item.

A `list` is not as flexible as a Javascript Array:

> Note that objects cannot be individually added to or removed from the list once created; to modify the contents of a list, it must be reassigned to a new list.

Though you can append to it:

> Values can be dynamically added to the list by using the push method, as if it were a JavaScript Array

More info here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-list.html

Comment: There's a very subtle but important piece to this answer, the declaration doesn't have a `:` at the end.  Until I figured that out I couldn't get it to work.