# QML ShapePath clear path elements

Tags: qt, qml, shapes, qqmllistproperty

I want to remove all path elements from my `ShapePath`. Since `pathElements` is a Qml list, the only way to modify it is by setting it to a new Javascript array. Therefore, I expected to be able to clear it by just assigning an empty array to it.

I tried `path.pathElements = []`, which does not work for me.

Then I tried `path.pathElements = null`, which does work (`PathLine` is no longer drawn), but it prints this ugly error message: `QObject::connect: Cannot connect (nullptr)::changed() to QQuickShapePath::processPath()`

Any other ideas?

Code to reproduce:

```
Shape {
    anchors.fill: parent

    ShapePath {
        id: path

        strokeWidth: 2
        strokeColor: "green"
        fillColor: "green"

        Component.onCompleted: path.pathElements = []

        PathLine { x: 50; y: 50 }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you're trying to remove the item dynamically, I wonder if the PathLine needs to be created dynamically?

Comment: In my real application I am actually creating them dynamically. But it does not work then, either

Comment: The problem could be that a list can also not be initialized with an empty array (see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61658194/qml-initialize-empty-list))

Comment: I filed a qt bug report: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-91366

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I filed a [bug report](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-91366) at Qt and they confirmed my bug.

The workaround until this gets fixed is to first assign `null`, followed by `[]`.

```
Shape {
    anchors.fill: parent

    ShapePath {
        id: path

        strokeWidth: 2
        strokeColor: "green"
        fillColor: "green"

        Component.onCompleted: {
            path.pathElements = null
            path.pathElements = []
        }

        PathLine { x: 50; y: 50 }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that's an old post, but a real solution exist better than the previous one

According to the datasheet, the pathLine appended to a shapePath consists of a list of PathElements (list) . So, a solution exist to clear a list in javascript

Path datasheet : https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-path.html

See my example, my shapePath is named cropPath:

```
    Shape{
        id: cropShape
        anchors.fill: parent
        property alias cropPath: cropPath
        ShapePath{
            id: cropPath

            startX: 0
            startY: 0
            fillColor: "#42ff00ff"
            strokeColor: "black"
            strokeWidth: 1
            dashPattern: [4, 5]
            strokeStyle: ShapePath.DashLine
            capStyle: ShapePath.RoundCap

        }
    }

function removePathElement(){
    cropPath.pathElements.splice(0, cropPath.pathElements.length)
}
```

an other solution is :

```
function removePathElement(){
    while (cropPath.pathElements.length > 0)
        cropPath.pathElements.pop()
}
```

according to this answer, the first solution is "a lot faster" :
[How do I empty an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232040/how-do-i-empty-an-array-in-javascript)

ps: thanks @skaldesh, your solution helped me a lot since I discovered that